# Is there a way to set the background color in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, colors, background

I would like to chnage the background color..  At first i tried to creat a vertical container, but this did not work becouse the edges wrapped arounbd the content, so there was a big right and left margin.
Ted

Comment: Background color of what, precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the screen background by:

```
Background myBG = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.RED);
getMainManager().setBackground(myBG);
```